# Awk/sed: add line numbers to text from within a range

Tags: awk, sed

So I have a range, say 2-4. And I have three lines:

```
first
second
third
```

I need my output to be:

```
2 first
3 second
4 third
```

I'm trying this on BSD (Mac) awk/sed, which seems to be making it harder.

Comment: What if you have more than 3 lines ?

Comment: Ah, I meant the question in a more general sense, in that the range given already matches the amount of lines. So if the range were 2-6 then we'd have 5 lines, etc.

Comment: Then there's no point saying _"I have a range..."_ You simply want to number all lines starting from `N` and that's really trivial... there's a tool that was designed specifically to `n`umber `l`ines.

Comment: Aha, that's true. There's me overcomplicating things again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html) is ideally suited:

```
nl -v2 -p -ba
```

will start counting from 2 (`-v2`), ignoring page changes (`-p`) and numbering all lines (`-ba`).

Answer (score 1):

POSIXLY:

```
awk '{printf("%s %s\n", FNR+1, $0)}' file
```

If you want to pass parameter:

```
awk -vn=2 '{printf "%s %s\n", n++, $0}' <file
```

If you want only the range is produced in case the file is longer than the range:

```
awk -v s=2 -v e=4 'BEGIN{for(n=s;n<=e;n++)print n}' | paste -d' ' - file
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure bash script?

```
i=2; cat output.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$i $line"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: That's [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), and see also [using while loop to process text considered bad practice in shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906).

Comment: In some limited Linux shells you will must need to use loops to process text, because you will not have any other tools. I now the cat is not necessary, is just an example to be replace with the very specific command the user are executing... But if there is really a output.txt file, they can use something like while ; bla; done <mygreatfile